# fixing JScrollPane with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jscrollpane

In order to add a background Image , I work on JLabels instead of JPanel .

```
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bg.png"));
    label.setLayout(new BoxLayout(label, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
         label.add(new JLabel(i.toString()));
    frame.add(label);
```

the problem here is that only components that fit the background image will be shown (in my example only the 10 first JLabels)

I tried using a JScrollPane

```
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(l);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
         label.add(new JLabel(i.toString()));
    frame.add(scroll);
```

but it didn't change much , so I tried using a JPanel

```
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(panel);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
         panel.add(new JLabel(i.toString()));
    label.add(scroll);
    frame.add(label);
```

so I got the JScrollPane working properly but the JPanel has covered the background image

what should I do ?

Here's the result to adding JLabels to label:

[image]

The result after adding them to the scroll:

[image]

And after adding `setOpaque(false)` to the `JPanel`:

[image]

Comment: set the `JPanel`'s opaque to false. But, for better help sooner please post a [mcve] and ASCII art / image of what you have and what you want to achieve, this will improve your post a lot. As you don't have enough reputation yet, you can add a link to your image and we can edit the post and make it show here

Comment: Also, as an aside recommendation, make your variables more descriptive, `l` what is `l`? I had to go up in the code to know what it was, instead call them `label` or `pane` / `panel` for the panels, `s` change it to `scroll` / `scrollPane` / etc; it will make the code easier to read and understand for you and for us

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: Well, then post a runnable example, the image, and follow my 2nd comment recommendations when doing so, so we can give more help

Comment: well here's the result to adding JLabels to label http://imgur.com/W0xMDdl
here's the result to adding them to scroll http://imgur.com/FOEf9M4
and here's when I set panel opaque to false http://imgur.com/TIlhgPS

Comment: And where's the [mcve]? You forgot to add it, please [edit] your question when you have done it and include the images there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the image as part of the `JPanel`'s `paintComponent()` method, then add the labels above it, then put that pane inside a `JScrollPane` and finally add it to the `JFrame`, for example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PanelWithBackgroundImage {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private Image img;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PanelWithBackgroundImage().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("JFrame with bg example");
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/home/jesus/Pictures/tokyo.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }
        };
        
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            pane.add(new JLabel("label " + i));
        }
        
        scroll = new JScrollPane(pane);
        
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image][image]

If you want the `JLabels` centered, you can change the `for` loop with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("label " + i);
    label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pane.add(label);
}
```

Which should look similar to this:

[image]

---

## Note:

You can copy-paste the code above, it should work, just change the image path, and that code, is called a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), next time, please post one which demonstrates what you have tried, not only parts of it, this way you'll get more, better and faster answers. Help us to help you! :)