# Java swing setSize

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem, I set the size for frame, but doesn't work. I found a topic about this, but it's not helpful for me...

I tried with `getContentPane().getSize(500,500)`, but nothing.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Mere extends JFrame{
    private JPanel b;
    public Mere(String titlu){
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(null);
        this.getSmth();
        pack();
        show();
    }
    public void getSmth(){
        JLabel user=new JLabel("User");
        user.setBounds(10,10,80,25);
        getContentPane().add(user);

        JTextField userText=new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100,10,160,25);
        getContentPane().add(userText);

        JPasswordField pas=new JPasswordField(20);
        pas.setBounds(100,40,160,25);
        getContentPane().add(pas);

        JButton n=new JButton("Register");
        n.setBounds(180,80,100,30);
        getContentPane().add(n);

        JLabel pass=new JLabel("Pass");
        pass.setBounds(10,40,100,25);
        getContentPane().add(pass);
        getContentPane().setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Mere("yas");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're calling `pack();` after calling `setSize()`.

   From the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack())

   > Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.

   So you rather override the `getPreferredSize()` method or remove the `pack()` call. See [Should I avoid the use of setPreferred/Maximum/MinimumSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) (YES)

   However the best practice would be to use a layout manager (as explanined below) and then call `pack()` and let the manager do it's job while calculating the `preferredSize` for you
2. Also you're using a `null` layout. Swing was designed to work with different PLAFs and screen sizes and resolutions, while pixel perfect GUIs might seem like the best and faster approach to make a complex GUI the more you advance in this the more problems you'll have in maintain it due to this, so go ahead and use a proper [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them. See [Null Layout is Evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)
3. Another thing is that you're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), see [SwingUtilities.invokeLater() why is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-needed) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476005/fixing-jscrollpane-with-jlabel/39480214#39480214) for an example on how to use it
4. Another thing I see is that you're extening `JFrame` which translated to english it says that your class **is a** `JFrame`, `JFrame` isn't flexible when you need to add it to another `Component`, instead you should create a `JFrame` instance and if you really need to extend something, extend from a `JPanel`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I used null as layout because it was easier.

Comment: Remember that easier isn't always the correct, once you learn to use a layout manager you'll see that it's easier to use them

Comment: Yes, you have right. I think that I'm gonna try GridBagLayout, anyway thanks for the tips :D

Comment: Remember that you can mix them, you can use a GridBagLayout with a FlowLayout with a BoxLayout and all the combinations you want

Comment: Now I need a little experience with layouts to make my program to look awesome.