# Java JPanel bigger than the JFrame with scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to create a JPanel in the size of the screen (It might be bigger than the JFrame) But I want the JFrame to be **resizable**. is it possible to see the hidden part of the JPanel (The part outside the JFrame) with scrolling (JScrollPane)?

*Its my first Java project so please explain your answers*

Example in html

```
<html>
<body> <!-- This is the JFrame -->
  <div style="width: 120%; height: 200%;"> <!-- This is the JPanel -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Paint Example
[Paint Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOtAt.png)

Comment: If you need an example you can look at Paint when the window is not full sized

Comment: So, from what I understand you want a scrollable `JPanel` inside a resizable `JPanel`? If so, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480214/2180785)

Comment: Take a look at his [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263438/paintcomponent-not-called-when-i-scroll-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollbars/66267763#66267763) showing a scrollable drawing JPanel.

Comment: *Its my first Java project* - learn Swing basics by reading the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) *please explain your answers*  - explain your question better by posting a [mre] demonstrating what you have tried.

Comment: "So, from what I understand you want a scrollable JPanel inside a resizable JPanel? If so," No i want a scrollable JPanel inside a resizable JFrame. But thanks for the links

Comment: "showing a scrollable drawing JPanel" I already created the drawing part

Comment: English is not my main language so its hard to write the question better but did u look at Paint behavior when the window is not full?

Comment: I know how to create a scrollable JPanel but I want it to be bigger than the JFrame

Comment: You override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your drawing panel. Read the Swing tutorial. There is a section on "Custom Painting" that contains a working example of how to do custom painting. You just adjust your preferred size.

Comment: And should I remove the setPreferdSize of the JSrollPane?

Comment: @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    }

Comment: That is in the JPanel extended class and the scroll pane is JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(canvas, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  //scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

Comment: canvas is the JPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that if anyone else needs you need to @Override getPreferredSize in the JPanel and **DONT add the JPanel to the JFrame**  create a JScrollPane with the JPanel and add the JScrollPane to the JFrame (I think my problem was that i added the JPanel twice)

EXAMPLE
-- In extended JFrame class

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(**SIZE**); // not tested I use @Override on the getPreferredSize - idea from camickr
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel, 
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

this.add(scroll);
```

Thanks for the help